# Can't do anything with .load()-ed content in jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm facing an interesting problem where everything works flawlessly. I console.log every step and it plays out just the way it should. But! I have a #div into what I .load(a-file.php). Now that "a-file.php" includes HTML mark-up as well, more specifically certain links that I'd like to make "active" onload.

Scenario; page load happens, Javascript loads and loads a file into the div. That div now has tabs and I'd like the first tab to be in an "active" state which requires me to addClass('active');. But the following seems to have no effect

```
$('#content').load('file.php'); // works.
$('#content a[rel="weird-page"]').addClass('active'); // does not work.
```

Any kind of help, even remotely nailing it, is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to:

```
$('#content').load('file.php', function() {
   $('#content a[rel="weird-page"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: You sir, are awesome. And I realized I probably would of found that out on the jQuery site itself, but my stupidity lead to asking a question here instead. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Codefoe make a habit of checking related docs/manual before start to code... that really helps.. anyways glad you got it.. :)

Comment: Will do! (But I gotta admit, it brings the lazy demons out to be able to just ask and get professional help in return).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `load()` works asynchronously and therefore your `addClass()` method is being called before `load()` has completed.

Using the `load()` callback function it will ensure your content has loaded:

```
$('#content').load('file.php', function() {
   $(this).find('a[rel="weird-page"]').addClass('active');
});
```

*shameless-plug-warning:* I wrote a [blog post about jQuery callback functions](http://curtistimson.net/Blog/Article/Using-jQuery-callback-functions) which you might find useful.

Comment: Your answer is more worth the up-vote than the one I gave it to, but since he was first and it did work, the rules of "first come, first served" applies. However, whatever the symbolic thank you's value these days is, Thank you. Read your post as well, bookmarked it for potential memory-loss in the future.

Comment: @Codefoe No problem, glad to help, and welcome to StackOverflow! For the record, you can up-vote multiple answers, but you can only "accept" one.

Comment: Right! I meant to say "accept" instead of up-vote as I do not yet have the privilege for the last one. If I get there, I'll be sure to correct my mistake. Also, thank you for the warm welcoming :)